# Where can I download JSTL taglibs? i.e. jstl.jar and standard.jar

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am following the Spring-MVC tutorial and currently I am on [part 2](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part2.html). The tutorial requires me to download `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`, which were once part of the Jakarta Taglibs project. The project has since moved to Apache, but when I go to [Apache's site](http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_taglibs-rdc.cgi). to download the taglibs, I get `403 Forbidden`.

So my question is, where can I download `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar`, so that I can get on with this tutorial?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can find them both in the Maven central repo:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/

Answer (score 20):

Since JSTL 1.1 is out of life, Apache has put it in the [archive](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/). Pick the `jakarta-taglibs-standard-current.zip` file.

However, if you're running a Servlet 2.5 compatible container  and the `web.xml` is declared as *at least* Servlet 2.5, then you should be able to use the new [JSTL 1.2](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) instead. Note that JSTL 1.2 does **not** require a `standard.jar`.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (available when you hover the [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl) and click *info*).

Comment: is apache jslt an extended version of sun jslt?

Comment: @manetic: no, it's just another implementation of JSTL, like as that Apache Tomcat is an implementation of JSP/Servlet and that Oracle (Sun) Glassfish is another one.

Comment: don't they do the same work? do you know which is standard, or most preferred?

Comment: @netic: JSTL *is* a standard API, so there's no such thing as "which one is standard". Both are. As for "preferred", it all comes down to the *implementation* of the API, and which runs "better" (faster, less memory, etc) in your particular server. Also note that the latest Apache/Jakarta JSTL is v1.1.2, while Sun/Oracle/Maven has 1.2 and latter